# How to scope only the tags a user has used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, tags

I am writing a Rails 4.2 app with models user, notecard, tag and tagging (for the m-2-m relationship).
A tag can have multiple notecards and a notecard can have multiple tags.
A card belongs to a user and a tag DOESN'T belong to a user.
How can I scope the tags that only a user has used?
I want to have an index of all tags and an index of the tags a user has actually used.

Thanks!

Here is the schema, as I don't have an idea on how to implement the where clause to index the tags a user has used.
to give you an idea, I'm looking for something like this

```
def index_of_used_tags
  #Take all tags, return those that have cards from this user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :folders
  has_many :cards
end
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :cards, through: :taggings

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :user_id
end
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :folder

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggins
end
```

---

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150604113358) do
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  create_table "cards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "object"
    t.text     "content"
    t.string   "source"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "folder_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
  add_index "cards", ["folder_id"], name: "index_cards_on_folder_id", using: :btree
  add_index "cards", ["user_id"], name: "index_cards_on_user_id", using: :btree
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id", using: :btree
  create_table "folders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
  add_index "folders", ["user_id"], name: "index_folders_on_user_id", using: :btree
  create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "card_id"
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
 add_index "taggings", ["card_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_card_id", using: :btree
 add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id", using: :btree
 create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "fname"
  t.string   "lname"
  t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
  t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
end
add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
add_foreign_key "cards", "folders"
add_foreign_key "cards", "users"
add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
add_foreign_key "folders", "users"
add_foreign_key "taggings", "cards"
add_foreign_key "taggings", "tags" end
```

Comment: can you paste your code, it would help to answer

Comment: done. i added the schema as am flying blind on the
def index_of_used_tags
  #Take all tags, return those that have cards from this user
end

Comment: Can you list all the associations between these classes please? (in your question, not a comment).

Comment: You can set up a `has_many` relationship between `User` and `Tagging` through `Card`.

Comment: added the models.
i think i got it actually. looking at it from the other side fo the telescope, having a block go through the array current_user.cards.tags should give me what i want, and retrieving the cards would be current_user.cards.tags.cards

trying it rn, will delete the question if it works

Comment: `current_user.cards.tags` won't work since `current_user.cards` would return a collection. Calling `tags` on it will give you NoMethodError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a `has_many through` relationship between User and Tag

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :folders
  has_many :cards
  has_many :tags, through: :cards
end
```

Then `user.tags` would give you all the tags the user has used.

Comment: in tags, can you see card_id?

Comment: `card_id` ? The relationship between `Card` and `Tag` is many-to-many.

Comment: If you want ids of all the cards of a user, you can do `user.card_ids`

Comment: my question was wrong..If you are using through cards then in cards table, we must have tag_id and user_id..right?

Comment: A `Card` belongs to a `User` so it will have `user_id`, but the relationship between `Card` and `Tag` is many-to-many so it won't have `tag_id`. `tag_id` will be there in `taggings` table.

Comment: In your case, is taggings table in a picture now?

Comment: user.tags is actually User -> cards -> taggings -> tags

Answer (score 0):

```
User.includes(:cards => :taggings).where('users.id = ?', current_user.id)
```

Try this query

Comment: Please add a little explanation. Just a fix isn't nearly as interesting as the why.